# ESRI geoevent cluster

Tags: arcgis-server, geoevent-processor

Is it possible to have geoevent in its own cluster? On a multinode server config I have only been able to get the first machine to run geoevent.  When I go to /geoevent/manager on a machine that is another cluster I get an error No Service found. There is nothing in the log to indicate a problem and I have confirmed the extension is authorized. Server 10.3.1.  It appears that in order for geoevent to function it is dependent on the first server.  Anyone have a different experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can not be done once you federate a server with portal you are affected by a bug.

BUG-000092043 : The GeoEvent Processor in a federated ArcGIS for Server and Portal for ArcGIS environment does not allow users to login to environments which utilizes a DNS name for their Portal site. When accessing the GeoEvent Processor login page, it prompts for Portal credentials, and even when using a PSA account to log in, the site displays a "The username or password you've entered is incorrect" error. The network traffic logged the following error "proxy?https://dns.domain.com/webadaptorsharing/generateToken", which is in relation to the site being unable to generate a token as it is missing a '/' between the ArcGIS Web Adaptor and the sharing identifiers in the URL.